# How to set priorities and annotations on Jersey filters

Tags: java, jersey

Imagine two filters and there annotations as follow:

```
@Provider
@ToTokenFilter
@Priority(1000)
public class TokenFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter() {
    // to do
  }
}

@Provider
@ToRootFilter
@Priority(2000)
public class RootFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter() {
    // to do
  }
}

@NameBinding
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ToTokenFilter {}

@NameBinding
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ToRootFilter {}
```

I'm trying to use this filters on a class, something like :

```
@Path("/users")
@ToTokenFilter
@ToRootFilter
public class Users {
  @GET
  public String getUsers() {
    //to do
  }
}
```

This way, my code is never going in my TokenFilter, and if I remove the @ToRootFilter, it's finally going. But I need both ! And I need TokenFilter to be call before RootFilter. That's why I did set priorities, I tried to put values priorities in both way but nothing is working.

I tried to put @ToTokenFilter on the class and @ToRootFilter on the method, but still the same issue.

Does someone knows how to use multiple filters with priorities and annotations with Jersey?

EDIT

here is the web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>filters.TokenFilter;filters.RootFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: FYI, looks like you're using Jersey 2.x, so your `<init-param>` is useless. That's a 1.x property

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works as expected for me. I used one single dependency for the test `jersey-container-servlet - 2.16`. Can you post your dependencies, along with a real example that you've tested that doesn't work, along with the import statements, and complete web.xml. It's pretty odd behavior, and I'd like to see what's causing it

Comment: Just posted an answer with the solution, thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem :

i was importing :

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Priority;
```

instead of

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
```

But jersey is using java Priority annotation to set Priority on filter.

By default, Priority was set to 5000 on all my filters, and the sequence was random i guess, sometimes using TokenFilter first, and sometimes RootFilter.
And my RootFilter function was stopping the request because it needed an attribute set in TokenFilter.